# Dynamically add sub menu items

Tags: menus

I have been able to add menu items with this statement, this however creates a flat menu.  The menu has been created already.  I just need to add items.

```
    wp_update_nav_menu_item(4, 0, array('menu-item-title' =>  __($post_title), 'menu-item-url' => home_url('/'.$url.'/'), 'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));
```

this is super simple to use.  How do I add a sub-menu item?

Comment: Did you created menu with submenus.?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Besides there are numerous "nav menu" questions here. I have written answer to some very complicated problems. Have you searched the site at all?

Comment: I have searched and nothing is exactly what I am looking for.  I just want to add things to an existing menu...

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I have found what I was looking for the function returns an id of the menu item needed.

```
    $my_menu_id = wp_update_nav_menu_item(4, 0, array('menu-item-title' => __($my_menu_title), 'menu-item-url' => home_url('/'.$url.'/'), 'menu-item-parent-id' => $my_menu_id, 'menu-item-status' => 'publish'));
```

by knowing the menu id you can then create sub menus attached to the first menu item using the menu-item-parent-id